# center div blocks but not in the last row

Tags: javascript, css

I'm really stuck with trying to keep div blocks centered with the exception of the last row.

Someone else already created this fiddle that kind of demonstrates my question. You can see how the blocks in the result panel stay centered even when the window is resized. I would like to have similar behavior BUT if the last row contains less blocks than the rows above, then that last row should not get centered but left aligned.

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zbbHc/1/

Someone might ask why I don't just use float:left. The problem with that is that I couldn't find a way of centering my blocks using that method without also specifying a fixed width for my wrapper. I'm trying to keep everything as liquid as possible.

Comment: Very interesting, I wonder if this can be done with pure CSS

Comment: How wide is your wrapper? Does it matter how many items are on a row?

Comment: Great question! As an expansion to @JohnC 's question, when you say do dont want to apply fixed width to your wrapper do you mean that you would prefer not to set a fixed width for the two "columns"?

Comment: As a potential answer, you could split the difference between fixed width and fluid width and specify a min-width

Comment: @JohnC My wrapper is 90% wide with 5% margins. I would like to have as many blocks in a row that can fit there.

Comment: @Zachary Yes I'm trying to avoid setting anything fixed in the horizontal direction. I would like the layout to stay as liquid as possible.

Comment: To answer your question: no, I don't believe this is possible in pure CSS. What I'd like to know is the context: what sort of information would benefit from being laid out this way?  Perhaps we can suggest alternatives.  Also, you tagged this javascript, so is a javascript solution adequate?

Comment: @ Zach Shipley The context is a gallery of product images that I want centered on the page. I feel like the last row's blocks being centered is a bad thing purely from a visual standpoint (the break the "grid"). Javascript solutions are also welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zbbHc/45/

Not sure, but I think this is the maximum we can do using CSS alone.

*Update:* (THis will not work in all cases, check the code below which work in all cases [I guess])

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB hide"></div>
    <div class="iB hide"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**​

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    text-align: center;
    text-align-last: left;
}

.iB {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
}
.iB.hide {
   visibility:hidden; 
}
```

​

**Here is the quick and dirty method using jQuery. This will add invisible elements automatically**

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/fD6fn/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<style>
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    text-align: center;
    text-align-last: left;
}

.iB {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
}
.iB.hide {
   visibility:hidden; 
}
​
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB"></div>
</div>
<script language="javascript">
function findHiddenElementCount() {
var $wrapper = $("#wrapper"),
    itemWidth = "200",
    count = "",
    itemCount = 7; 

    count = $wrapper.width()/itemWidth;

// Some wild logic below, can be optimized.
return parseInt(count) - (itemCount - (parseInt(itemCount/parseInt(count)) * parseInt(count))) ;
}



function addInvisibleElements() 
{
    // Delete invisible items
    $("#wrapper .iB.hide").remove();


    var c = findHiddenElementCount();

    for(var i = 0; i < c;i++)
    {
        $("#wrapper").append('<div class="iB hide"></div>');
    }

}

$(window).bind("resize",addInvisibleElements); // resize handler

$(document).ready(addInvisibleElements); // take care during page load

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in Chrome that results in everything being aligned left.

Comment: I think you should check that again and play around with your browser size. It seems to work perfectly for me, except that when I get my window to large I need to add more hidden rows. Depending on what the OP is after, a mix of this and Javascript, or just add a large number of hidden rows should work.

Comment: I find this a pretty interesting suggestion, although there are some negative aspects of this approach, the main concern being that the hidden blocks cause the wrapper to extend vertically longer than it should extend..
Another problem (for me) is that I have no idea how to use javascript to determine the amount of invisible blocks that should be inserted in different situations.

Comment: Its fairly simple to figure out how many hidden blocks you need. On the window resize event you can check the position of each block to see how many are in the top row. Do a little math and you know the number of hidden blocks to append to the bottom. I'll write up a sample.

Comment: Here is the example if find the number of blocks to append: http://jsbin.com/arunic/11/edit

Comment: @kiranvj Your update with jQuery does the job, even though the complexity of the solution is a bit disappointing. It does work though, so I'm marking this as the answer.

Comment: The code I posted is a very basic version, need to optimize more, also we can make it less complex ;)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use percentage? http://jsfiddle.net/zbbHc/38/ that's how most of fluid layouts usually work

Comment: That's not centered. In Chrome, at least.

Comment: align-center is a really old and now a bad solution, something that people should stop using, there are a lot of ways to center things, check twitter bootstrap, 960.gs fluid and you will find great examples of how fluid layouts work http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html

Comment: @Paradise makes a good point, though. Normally in a "fluid" layout you'd strive to work solely with relative units.

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'if' the last row has fewer blocks do you mean that it's dynamic content? If you know it will have one then you can just position it relatively to the value of half its own width(and any margins etc)

```
.iB:last-child{
   position:relative;
   left:-100px;
   background:blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zbbHc/54/

Comment: Hi! I can't know how many blocks are in the last row since I don't know the browser window size of a possible user. If the browser window is very wide, more blocks fit in one row ect.

Comment: aah i see. hmm, in that case I don't think the DOM would necessarily be registering what we see on the screen in rows, as 'rows', if it's just putting as many items in one line before breaking line it won't recognise rows. I could well be wrong. I'm going to research! interesting question!

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to do this with a table (though I tend to try to avoid tables). Table-cells' dimensions are determined by their contents (of course, you can add your own, or max/min dimensions). You could have a table with one column and (although it's not best practice) embed divs into the table (each div being a block).

The width of the table would be fluid because it would be based on the width of the widest cell (thus, the blocks will line up nicely and will look very neat), and you could hard-code or script (of course, I suggest scripting) a style/method to check if the last row contains less blocks, and if it does to set the text-align to left for that cell, only.

This solution could probably use some improvement, but it may be a good start, depending on what your going to use this for.