# Make a div fit inline-block content

Tags: html, css

How can I make a div scale to fit its content - if that content is a collection of inline-blocks?

I would like to do this in order to center several rows of divs, but have the last partial row left-aligned with those above.

```css
#outer {
    border: 4px solid red;
    text-align: center;
}

#inner {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 4px solid blue;
    text-align: left;
}

.block {
    display: inline-block;   
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Link to JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/8f8yhn09/)

As you can see from the JSFiddle, the blue inner div remains as wide as it's red parent (despite being inline-block itself and it's content not filling it). This causes the green blocks to remain left aligned.

You may need to resize the JSFiddle output to make some whitespace to the right of the  green blocks to test this.

Here is roughly how it should look afterwards (if there are seven blocks over three rows):
[image]

Comment: i think, understanding your question is more complicated than this implementation ! - can you make it more simple! like use images and explain, what you are getting, and image with what you want?

Comment: by content do you mean the blue container?

Comment: Quite simply...you can't, that's not the way the wrapping model works (AFAIK). It's a common request and the answer is a javascript one unfortunately.

Comment: if you want to align all the blocks to the centre instead of left just update `#inner{text-align:center}`

Comment: There is code and JSFiddle to show what I am getting. I have added an image to show what I want.

Comment: Its causing that big gap due to the wrapping. One solution (not a fun one) would be to make a few different media queries to handle its width based on the size of the boxes.

Comment: Andrew - content is green boxes, it is the blue container I want to scale to fit them.

Comment: @PaulS How exactly do you want to fit them? Do you want to force 3 items per row? and in the solution you are looking for do you want to avoid setting container's width manually?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what you can do to keep it responsive yet centered:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n0vfx2pg/1/)

It uses media queries based on the the box widths:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1068px) {

    #inner {
        max-width: 866px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 898px) {
    #inner {
        max-width: 692px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 728px) {
    #inner {
        max-width: 518px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 558px) {
    #inner {
        max-width: 344px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 388px) {
    #inner {
        max-width: 170px;
    }
}
```

A bit tedious, but with a little math it is pretty easy.

The reason it won't work solely with `display: inline-block` is because when the boxes wrap, the blue div assumes the entire space (left and right) is to be used. It doesn't understand where the wrap begins.

Comment: Thanks, not what I went with, but this is a good solution so have +1ed.

Answer (score 0):

Since your block's with and margin are manually defined in your css just set the with of your div with id="inner" to "520px"!!!

Answer (score 0):

here's one solution with a set width. the variable width is hard because you have the contents inside the blue box that is `inline-block` so the extra space on the right is due to the wrapping.

```css
#outer {
    border: 4px solid red;
    text-align: center;
}

#inner {
    border: 4px solid blue;
    text-align: left;
    width: 520px;
    margin: auto;
}

.block {
    display: inline-block;   
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else finds this post, here is what I ended up doing:

I added several extra hidden blocks, one pixel high, so that the last row of visible blocks were lined up.

http://jsfiddle.net/bw8mm1gq/

It doesn't quite answer the question I asked, but does solve the problem I had.

Thanks to dwreck08 who also had a decent solution, that did answer my question.

I got the idea from here:
[center div blocks but not in the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691030/center-div-blocks-but-not-in-the-last-row)

```css
#outer {
    border: 4px solid red;
    text-align: center;
}


.block {
    display: inline-block;   
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    margin: 10px;
}

.spacer {
    display: inline-block;   
    width: 150px;
    height: 1px;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
```